# How can you solve this type of (not quite linear) diophantine equation in 2 variables?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a general technique to find solutions of this type of equation?

555555=t+2rt+r

I'll provide the only answer I know in the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: t=2324 and r=119 is a solution (the only one that I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ 2rt + r + t = N  $$
$$ 4rt + 2r + 2t = 2N  $$
$$ 4rt + 2r + 2t + 1 = 2N + 1  $$
$$ (2r+1)(2t+1) = 2N + 1 $$